Redundant use of <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> in Angular material table
Is there a way to remove this redundant use of <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> for the table cells ?
Here's my code
for each cell definition i have to provide the element .can i not provide the definition only once for all the cells of the table or at least a row
<body>
  <div class="table">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="appointments">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="vehicleNumber">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Vehicle Number</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          {{ element.vehicleNumber }}
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="ownerName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Owner Name</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          {{ element.ownerName }}
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="ownerContact">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Owner Contact</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          {{ element.ownerContact }}
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="appointmentDate">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Appointment Date</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          {{ element.appointmentDate | date : "fullDate" }}
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="serviceStatus">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Service Status</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          {{ element.serviceStatus }}
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="editAppointment">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Edit Appointment</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
          <a
            mat-raised-button
            color="Primary"
            (click)="change(i)"
            [routerLink]="'/editAppointment/' + i"
            >Edit
          </a>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="deleteAppointment">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Delete Appointment</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
          <a
            mat-raised-button
            color="warn"
            [routerLink]="'/deleteAppointment/' + i"
            >Delete</a
          >
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columndefs"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columndefs"></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>




i tried to find an solution but it seems that assigning matcelldef is necessary for each cell.
